# ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy how many?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(locator)
```

How webDriver knows how many elements are located for presence by the locator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the code, it just grabs all elements that match the provided locator. The only thing it catches is `StaleElementReferenceException`. The full code is below with a link to the source.

```
/// <summary>
/// An expectation for checking that all elements present on the web page that
/// match the locator.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="locator">The locator used to find the element.</param>
/// <returns>The list of <see cref="IWebElement"/> once it is located.</returns>
public static Func<IWebDriver, ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement>> PresenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By locator)
{
    return (driver) =>
    {
        try
        {
            var elements = driver.FindElements(locator);
            return elements.Any() ? elements : null;
        }
        catch (StaleElementReferenceException)
        {
            return null;
        }
    };
}
```

https://github.com/DotNetSeleniumTools/DotNetSeleniumExtras/blob/master/src/WaitHelpers/ExpectedConditions.cs

Answer (score 1):

**Key Point:** Find all elements within the current page using the given By mechanism
to locate elements within a document with the help of locator value.

When implicitly waiting, this method will return as soon as there are more than 0 items in the found collection, or will return an empty list if the timeout is reached.

Answer (score 0):

`presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy` will check of presence of atleast one element then it will return all the elements that matches the provided locator.

Here is the official documentation from method implementation.

> An expectation for checking that there is at least one element present
>       on a web page.
>
> locator is used to find the element
>
> returns the list of WebElements once they are located

Here is the official link to the java doc.
https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy-org.openqa.selenium.By-